# Iterate over dictionaries' entries inside a list in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that sits inside of a list in python. How do I iterate over it? I need to get at both the keys and the values:

```
 z = (client.list_signing_certificates(UserName=user_name)['Certificates'])
print(z)
[{'UserName': 'tdunphy', 'CertificateId': 'MSLQC5IFBTSNJOBEMIYXNN3DWC372237', 'CertificateBody': '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nUWQqyrpL83zcGAfIa3hyez3iEZ/P9zMEPSuhuwIbIA==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n', 'Status': 'Active', 'UploadDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 13, 32, 31, tzinfo=tzutc())}, {'UserName': 'tdunphy', 'CertificateId': 'JPVTB5JCCAZ4COLGLG3QT2E2HBRKVZZP', 'CertificateBody': '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nxmMtlfD3C3ju4bH9+bO2rymBynJldfARujrv0oVTcw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n', 'Status': 'Active', 'UploadDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 13, 35, 2, tzinfo=tzutc())}]
```

There are 2 certificates in the list. I need to get at both. If there are more certificates I need to get at those too. It varies based on the user.

I am using python 3.

Comment: Why don't you get the first element in the list and process the dict?

Comment: Seems like `list(d[0].items())` is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the list, then iterate over the dictionary items:

```py
for element in z:
    for key, value in element.items():
        print("Key is: ", key)
        print("Value is: ", value)
```

`dict.items()` returns a tuple that contains each key and the associated value.

Otherwise, if you only need keys you can use `dict.keys()`, or, if you only need values, you can use `dict.values()`.

Edit:

If what you are looking is to get the certificate body then you don't even need to iterate the dictionaries, you could do:

```py
certificates = []

for element in z:
   certificates.append(element["CertificateBody"])
```

or as a comprehension:

```py
certificates = [element["CertificateBody"] for element in z]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don t know whats the problem exactly:

```
a={'a':1,'b':3}
b= {'c':1,'d':3}
l=[a,b]
for i in l :
    print(i)
    print(i.keys())
    print(i.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You just get a dictionary and then iterate over items of dictionary.

```
for key, value in z[0].items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: I think you mean you get a list, you index the first element (as you've done), and *then* you iterate over the dictionary that resides in that index? The code is correct, but the explanation is not so great.

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate through the list first. Then for every dictionary in the list, iterate through the dictionary.

```
for i, d in z:
    for y, value in d:
        print(key)
        print(value)
```

Comment: OK, but there are 2 certificates in this list. And I need to get at both of them. If there are more I need to get to those as well. It varies based on user.

Comment: `.first()` is not a list method. Are you confusing this with something else?

Comment: @bluethundr I have modified my answer for you.

Comment: @Geekfish you are right, I confused list.first() and first(list).